# java.io.IOException at com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceImpl.translateException(FileServiceImpl.java:586)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am getting the following error in local as well as production. I am using SDK1.6.3. @production I have also added XXXXXXXX@appspot.gserviceaccount.com in Team tab of the "google api console".

```
  FileService fileService = FileServiceFactory.getFileService(); 
  GSFileOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder = new GSFileOptionsBuilder() .setBucket(BUCKETNAME) .setKey(FILENAME) .setMimeType("text/html") .setAcl("public_read") .addUserMetadata("myfield1", "my field value"); 
  AppEngineFile writableFile = fileService.createNewGSFile(optionsBuilder.build());
```

This is my code and I am getting error on

```
AppEngineFile writableFile = fileService.createNewGSFile(optionsBuilder.build());
```

The above code I have used and getting following error..

```
java.io.IOException
    at com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceImpl.translateException(FileServiceImpl.java:586)
    at com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceImpl.makeSyncCall(FileServiceImpl.java:561)
    at com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceImpl.create(FileServiceImpl.java:479)
    at com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceImpl.createNewGSFile(FileServiceImpl.java:149)
    at com.yamaha.StogareTestServlet.doGet(StogareTestServlet.java:34)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:60)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:78)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:363)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$ApplicationException: ApplicationError: 705: Parameter x-goog-meta-myfield1 is not supported
    at com.google.appengine.api.files.dev.LocalFileService.throwError(LocalFileService.java:196)
    at com.google.appengine.api.files.dev.FileMetadata.checkParameters(FileMetadata.java:211)
    at com.google.appengine.api.files.dev.GSFile.create(GSFile.java:98)
    at com.google.appengine.api.files.dev.LocalFileService.create(LocalFileService.java:217)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$AsyncApiCall.callInternal(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:498)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$AsyncApiCall.call(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:452)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$AsyncApiCall.call(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:430)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedCallable$1.run(Executors.java:463)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedCallable.call(Executors.java:460)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:885)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

Caused by:
com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$ApplicationException: ApplicationError: 705: Parameter x-goog-meta-myfield1 is not supported
    at com.google.appengine.api.files.dev.LocalFileService.throwError(LocalFileService.java:196)
    at com.google.appengine.api.files.dev.FileMetadata.checkParameters(FileMetadata.java:211)
    at com.google.appengine.api.files.dev.GSFile.create(GSFile.java:98)
    at com.google.appengine.api.files.dev.LocalFileService.create(LocalFileService.java:217)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$AsyncApiCall.callInternal(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:498)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$AsyncApiCall.call(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:452)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$AsyncApiCall.call(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:430)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedCallable$1.run(Executors.java:463)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedCallable.call(Executors.java:460)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:885)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Please Help me out. Thanks in advance - Shri Kant

Comment: This is an interesting problem. Does it also happen in production in addition to the local version?

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply... Yes this problem comes in production also. Should I remove meta field from my code??

Answer (score 0):

Please upgrade to the latest version of the Java SDK (1.8.0 as of May 18th, 2013): https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_Java

Current versions of the SDK no longer contain the stack trace you list in the bug:

```
at com.google.appengine.api.files.dev.LocalFileService.throwError(LocalFileService.java:196)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to go to the source code for com.google.appengine.api.files.GSFileOptions (gae java sdk 1.8.1.1) to be able to find out what a valid bucket name should be.

Line 37: this.fileName = FileServiceImpl.GS_FILESYSTEM_PREFIX + bucket + "/" + key;

The Javadoc does not provide any information on the format of the bucket. In this case do not include the /gs/ prefix or / at the end in your bucket name (like I was doing.) If you have used other APIs (like the [BlobStor API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/#using-blobstore-with-gcs)) this can be confusing since they require the /gs/ prefix.

I was getting the same exception and stack trace with 1.8.1.1 so a bad bucket name can be the cause.

Also, you may want to try the [Google Cloud Storage Client Library](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/#about_the_google_cloud_storage_gcs_client_library).